# How to combine multiple csv files

Tags: python, concatenation, google-colaboratory

I have a folder filled with MANY files, each with two columns of data in it. I have been playing with this code, but I don't think the columns are concatenating correctly. I always get a message that there is not enough RAM or just that it crashed. I've tried other codes, but have gotten an error that there are no objects to be concatenated.

```
os.chdir("/content/drive/My Drive/Full Low Temps") 
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
#combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
#export to csv
combined_csv.to_csv( "combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')`
```

Comment: Did you try using `cat` instead of Python? Should be as simple as `cat "/content/drive/My Drive/Full Low Temps/*.csv" >combined_csv.csv`

Comment: Do you have header lines at the start of each csv file? In any case,  if you do not want to use a linux/mac tool like cat, you can use python, but read one line at a time and then output the line, rather than trying to load it all into memory.